# Why does the Dow Jones Industrial Average index go up in the long run although the constituents have changed since created?

Tags: stock-markets, djia

I'm aware that there are 30 constituents in the Dow Jones Industrial Average and has always been since the index was created in 1896, but why and how does this index keep going up in the long run since created although the underlying constituents have changed?

Comment: Why do you think that a change in the constituents should stop it from going up? Without knowing that, it’s hard to pin down your misconception.

Comment: What makes the index go up in the long run?

Comment: So what does the change in the constituents of the DJIA have to do with your question? What is its relevance?

Comment: I agree that the market as a whole returning profit over time is that on average, businesses are profitable, and owning a share of the business means you earn a share of the profits. But how does changing the constituents make the index keep going up? (e.g. hypothetically speaking for illustration: 30 DJIA companies in 1896 makes the DJIA go up to 381 points in 1929, but if all the constituents have changed in 1960, resulting DJIA in 681 points, and again if all the constituents have changed in 2000, resulting DJIA in 10729 points, then what makes the DJIA keeps increasing over 100 years?

Comment: Changing constituents doesn’t make the index go either up or down. If done properly it has no effect on the direction of movement, which is why I’m asking what its relevance is to your question.

Comment: I think a good way to think about it is an index normalizes the stock performance of a segment so that it is comparable over time. Changing what companies make up the index do not change the indexes value, simply because it by definition is normalized.

Comment: The change in constituents helps the index rise, due to survivorship bias.

Comment: @BenVoigt, sort of true but not. If 30 originally chosen companies no longer exist, then what use is the index? It kind of misses the entire point of an index to never change the companies that represent a particular segment, since a market isn’t static with time. Though, perhaps you meant this from a tongue in cheek perspective.

Comment: @JarrodChristman: I really do mean that there is a survivorship bias effect.  When a company starts to decline (whether due to poor management, or obsolescence of its industry, or whatever) it gets dropped from the index and its place is taken by a new company that has growth momentum.  I'm not saying the resulting increase in the index is made more useful by this effect, since it's possible that over the long term the index does better than any single company...  but it does affect the index.

Answer (score 4):

What makes the market as a whole return a profit over time is that businesses, on average, are profitable, and owning a share of the business means you earn a share of the profits. This drives the basic "market rate of return", which over the long run has averaged somewhere around 8%.

Whether that is expressed as dividends, share price growth, or both varies from stock to stock, though there has been what I consider an unhealthy shift of emphasis to share price growth at the cost of lower dividends; this pressure creates some perverse incentives for upper management.

The Dow, S&P, etc. are selected subsets which try to provide a summary of (a portion of) the market. Since in average the market is trending upward in the long run, they do too.

Comment: I agree that the market as a whole returning profit over time is that on average, businesses are profitable, and owning a share of the business means you earn a share of the profits. But how does changing the constituents make the index keep going up? (e.g. hypothetically speaking for illustration: 30 DJIA companies in 1896 makes the DJIA go up to 381 points in 1929, but if all the constituents have changed in 1960, resulting DJIA in 681 points, and again if all the constituents have changed in 2000, resulting DJIA in 10729 points, then what makes the DJIA keeps increasing over 100 years?

Comment: It doesn't. Changing the constituents is about continuing to (try to approximately) track the average of the specific segment of the market that index claims to represent, while not being too complicated to be manageable. If you're tracking large companies, which ones are considered how large changes over time. Ditto for any other subset -- tech, high-dividend, low or high risk. After setting that balance to the index author's best guess, it does what it does. The Dow increases because the market segment it tries to represent increases.

Answer (score 3):

If a new constituent is added, and another one dropped is because the newly added better suits the criteria for the index than the old one.

The index level does not change at all with this (simple math). What changes is the profitability and size of the companies.

I honestly find the question mind boggling if you know what an index is. Think of the SPX; it contains more or less the 500 biggest / most successful companies on the US. Do you think the biggest 500 companies in the US are bigger today or a 100 years ago? If you think the former, you should also understand why the index grew.

Comment: And the biggest companies today are a very different set from what they were 100 years ago. The index mix reflects that rather than anticipating that.

Answer (score 1):

The index has a divisor. When securities are added or removed from the index, the divisor is adjusted, as well as when there are corporate actions such as stock dividends and stock splits.  Read these at [Investopedia](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/i/indexdivisor.asp) and [Schwab](https://www.schwab.com/learn/story/what-happens-when-stocks-index-change)